# "pod init" creates error that says "You need at least git version 1.8.5 to use CocoaPods"

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, command-line-tool

I was not able to install any pod in my system.
Hence, I removed cocoapods from my Mac and then reinstalled it.
The process was successful but when I run the command `pod init` following error shows up in the terminal:

```
`verify_minimum_git_version!': [!] You need at least git version 1.8.5 to use CocoaPods (Pod::Informative)
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.2.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:49:in `run'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.2.1/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
```

I also checked my Git version which was 1.8.4 but I am getting any solution to update the same.

Comment: Try this :Xcode Preferences -> 
Locations -> 
Selected the Command Lin Tools: select Xcode 8.3 or run this command sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app

Comment: Already did this, not working :(

Comment: it may help you https://modulesunraveled.com/installing-git/updating-git-if-you-have-version-apple-well-official-install

Comment: @IshikaCheck this one  [Pod file not being initialized ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41996429/pod-file-not-being-initialized)

Comment: @VigneshDavins: Tried Already

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Firstly remove the existing git in your system using commands:-

Use command "which git"
that will give u the path say "/usr/local/bin/git", then use command->$ sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/git

This will remove existing git from your system
Then reinstall git again

```
$ brew install git
```

It might issue a warning saying

`` Warning: git 2.13.2 is already installed, it's just not linked.
You can use `brew link git` to link this version. ``

Then run below mentioned command:-

```
$ sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/share/
$ sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/lib
$ brew link --overwrite --dry-run git
```

It might give you error

`Error: Could not symlink share/git-core/templates/description
Target /usr/local/share/git-core/templates/description
already exists. You may want to remove it:
  rm '/usr/local/share/git-core/templates/description'`

To force the link and overwrite all conflicting files:
  brew link --overwrite git

To list all files that would be deleted:
  brew link --overwrite --dry-run git

Then finally run command

```
$ brew link --overwrite git
```

This is how I updated my git and pod init worked. Hope you find it helpful :)

Comment: Thank you pradeep, your solution worked well for me. Moreover, I also had to create master using command "$ git clone https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git master" and do the cloning in order to install pod.

Comment: Before doing this, please see [Krunal's answer](/a/46451798). You may not need to perform this at all.

Comment: This solution is also work at my end. Thank you for details information.

Answer (score 211):

> **It needs to set your command line tool version, in your Xcode (Preferences).**

You can download latest command line tool from [Apple Download Portal](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id497799835?ls=1&mt=12), if you have paid apple developer account/id.

Here are current stable and beta Xcode Tools and supporting command line tool download links. (Ensure you're logged in using premium developer account on Apple Developer Account to access these links)

> **Xcode 11**
>
> - [Xcode 11.2 beta 2](https://developer.apple.com/services-account/download?path=/Developer_Tools/Xcode_11.2_beta_2/Xcode_11.2_beta_2.xip)
>     
>    - [(Command Line Tool (Xcode 11.2 beta 2) - for macOS 10.14)](https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Command_Line_Tools_for_Xcode_11.2_beta_2/Command_Line_Tools_for_Xcode_11.2_beta_2.dmg)
> - [Xcode 11](https://developer.apple.com/services-account/download?path=/Developer_Tools/Xcode_11/Xcode_11.xip)
>     
>    - [(Command Line Tool (Xcode 11) - for macOS 10.14)](https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Command_Line_Tools_for_Xcode_11/Command_Line_Tools_for_Xcode_11.dmg)
>
> **Xcode 10**
>
> - [Xcode 10.2.1](https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_10.2.1/Xcode_10.2.1.xip)
>     
>    - [(Command Line Tool (Xcode 10.2.1) - for macOS 10.14)](https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Command_Line_Tools_macOS_10.14_for_Xcode_10.2.1.dmg/Command_Line_Tools_macOS_10.14_for_Xcode_10.2.1.dmg)
> - [Xcode 10.2](https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_10.2/Xcode_10.2.xip)
>     
>    - [(Command Line Tool (Xcode 10.2) - for macOS 10.14)](https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Command_Line_Tools_macOS_10.14_for_Xcode_10.2/Command_Line_Tools_macOS_10.14_for_Xcode_10.2.dmg)
> - [Xcode 10.1](https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_10.1/Xcode_10.1.xip)
>     
>    - [(Command Line Tool (Xcode 10.1) - for macOS 10.14)](https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Command_Line_Tools_macOS_10.14_for_Xcode_10.1/Command_Line_Tools_macOS_10.14_for_Xcode_10.1.dmg)
>     
>    - [(Command Line Tool (Xcode 10.1) - for macOS 10.13)](https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Command_Line_Tools_macOS_10.13_for_Xcode_10.1/Command_Line_Tools_macOS_10.13_for_Xcode_10.1.dmg)
> - [Xcode 10](https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_10/Xcode_10.xip)
>     
>    - [(Command Line Tool (Xcode 10) - for macOS 10.14)](https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Command_Line_Tools_macOS_10.13_for_Xcode_10/Command_Line_Tools_macOS_10.13_for_Xcode_10.dmg)
>     
>    - [(Command Line Tool (Xcode 10) - for macOS 10.13)](https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Command_Line_Tools_macOS_10.14_for_Xcode_10/Command_Line_Tools_macOS_10.14_for_Xcode_10.dmg)

Once you've latest command line tool installed in your system, set it from Xcode Menu.

> **(Xcode Menu Items) Xcode ► Preferences ► Location ► Command Line Tool ► Select appropriate command line tool**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 13):

I had a similar issue after installing a second `Xcode`.
As a result there was no `command line tools` specified in `xcode-select -p`

Fixed by manually choosing newer `Xcode` version

Comment: This worked for me! For anyone else attempting to fix the issue this way on the command line - the command to manually choose the newer version of Xcode is `sudo xcode-select --switch /path/to/latest/Xcode.app` (the command must be run as root)

Comment: For those who want to get xcode location munally: 

1) Open terminal
2) Drag and drop xcode on terminal
3) Terminal will write your xcode location for example: /Applications/Xcode
4) Select with mouse cursor the text you want to copy, in this case location of xcode.

Than your run: sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode

Answer (score 0):

I came across this answer after installing latest version of XCode 9.3 -

I was trying to do a -

- Pod Update  [ or --version, or any pod command ...]
- I tried to "brew install git" like in the top answer but there was all kinds of complaints about no access to Cellar, then when I added access, missing c compilers ..

The command line tools setting in Locations in Xcode Preferences showed command latest 9.3 line tools installed "correctly", but after reading the above answers I decided to install it again using -

```
xcode-select --install
```

After the download / install, pod started working again, was still having issues with brew which was a high sierra issue. fixed with - 
https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/3285.

Answer (score 0):

1. Run the command
   `$ brew install git`
2. Then navigate to your project folder and type `pod init`

These steps worked for me