# "Failed to extract git version" CocoaPods using Mac

Tags: swift, ruby, xcode, cocoapods

I need some help. I am trying to install CocoaPods to my mac and I receive the following error when I get to the "pod setup" part of the process. Any ideas?

```
Nathans-MacBook-Air:~ nathannoel$ pod setup --verbose

/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:118:in 
`git_version': Failed to extract git version from `git --version`
("xcrun: error: invalid active developer path
  (/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer), missing xcrun at: 
   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcrun\n") (RuntimeError)
  from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:130:in 
 `verify_minimum_git_version!'
  from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:49:in `run'
  from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
  from /usr/local/bin/pod:22:in `load'
  from /usr/local/bin/pod:22:in `<main>'

Nathans-MacBook-Air:~ nathannoel$
```

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28706428/invalid-active-developer-path-on-mac-os-x-after-installing-ruby

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46451798/6746324