# Problem with using Cocoapods on my projects?

Tags: xcode, git, cocoapods

I recently reformated my Macbook and lost all my projects, luckily I had them all up on my GitHub page so I downloaded them all again

the problem is when I try to install pods using "pod install" Cocoapods returns an error that goes like this:

```
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.7.0/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:118:in `git_version': Failed to extract git version from `git --version` ("") (RuntimeError)
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.7.0/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:130:in `verify_minimum_git_version!'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.7.0/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:49:in `run'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.7.0/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/bin/pod:22:in `load'
from /usr/local/bin/pod:22:in `<main>'
```

I already removed Git and Cocoapods and reinstalled them & I selected the Git version in the drop down menu from Xcode/locations and nothing changed

Comment: git might not be findable in the path

Comment: @PaulBeusterien how can I make it findable in the path please?

Comment: Make sure git is installed?

Comment: @evolutionxbox i'm sure it's installed

Comment: Have you double checked?

Comment: @evolutionxbox "command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates"

Comment: @evolutionxbox i just created a new project to see if cocoapods works and it works on the new project. it doesn't work on the older project for some reason??

Comment: Could you also check in the command line by typing `git --version`?

Comment: @evolutionxbox it returns: "git version 2.21.0
" ... cocoapods works on new projects i created but it gives me that error when using downloaded projects from github

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51660534/failed-to-extract-git-version-cocoapods-using-mac?noredirect=1&lq=1 is related

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Invalid active developer path on MAC OS X after installing Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28706428/invalid-active-developer-path-on-mac-os-x-after-installing-ruby)